# How to use replace all

Tags: java, markdown

How can I replace some values? For example, I want to replace `#text` with `<h1>text</h1>`, and similarly, replace `##text` with `<h2>text</h2>`. When I do it, only the first replacement I made for h1 is replaced.

```
private String getText;

    //private 

    public String Test(EditText edittext) {

        getText = edittext.getText().toString();

        String replace = getText.replace("# (.+)", "<h1>$1</h1>");

        replace = getText.replaceAll("## (.+)", "<h2>$1</h2>");

        return replace;

    }
```

Comment: `# (.+)` will not match `#text`, since there's no whitespace in it that your pattern is looking for. It would, however, match `# text`.

Comment: Once you replace `# foo`, there are no more `## foo`s to replace: they're now `#<h1>foo</h1>`.

Comment: This isn't to answer your question, but I think it would be better to just take a String as the method parameter rather than an EditText. This reduces dependencies. Just my 2 cents

Comment: @ControlAltDel definitely! You'd want that if only for unit testing.

Comment: Your first line calls `.replace`, not `replaceAll`

Comment: also note that `"# (.+)"` will match EVERYTHING after `"# "` (hash and space as explained in first [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76907145/how-to-use-replace-all#comment135578776_76907145)) - maybe you meant to put the space at the end like  `"#(.+) "` (will fail on the end of the input) - same for `"##..."`

Comment: The line `String replace = getText.replace("# (.+)", "<h1>$1</h1>");`  accomplishes nothing since the next line immediately overwrites `replace`.

Comment: Are all such tags at the start of the line? If so, add `^` to the start of the search term. And use `replaceAll()`

Comment: (by EVERYTHING I mean to the end of the line if not using the DOTALL option - otherwise to the end of the input string)

Comment: Could we see some sample input please?